# Spring Map<Object, Object> Injection

Tags: spring, velocity, code-injection, dictionary

I have been trying following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
................
>


<bean id="dateBean" class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.NumberTool"/>

<bean id="service" class="package.xyz">
    <property name="toolMap">
    <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="number"><ref:bean="dateBean"/></entry>
    </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As you can see this is for Velocity Tool Configuration.

I get this exception :

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'util:map'.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be   found for element 'util:map'.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

**Updated**: I have added the XML declarations .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<util:map>` for this use-case. That is actually an alias for a `MapFactoryBean`.
Use the classic `<map>` element instead and it should work.

Comment: I used <map> with <util:map>, removed util namespace and kept everything else same ,  however I get an exception:    Element type "ref:bean" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Comment: For map, you should use `<entry key="number" value-ref="date-bean"/>`

Comment: I have also tried that: I get following exception:     Key type [class java.lang.Object] of map [java.util.Map] must be assignable to [java.lang.String]

Comment: Can you show me the declaration of the toolMap property in your service class ?

Comment: what is the difference between <util:map> and <map>? will I have to configure MapFactoryBean in order to use <util:map>?

Comment: No, not at all. util:map is used for declaring a named bean of type map, while <map> is used for property injection. AFAIK, <map> just instantiates a LinkedHashMap, no FactoryBean involved... but I'll check again as this info may be outdated (or simply wrong)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I corrected the Map type and it works. I couldn't find any helpful link to point out <util:map> and <map> differences. If you can provide any such link it will be great.

Comment: Actually, I've been looking for one myself... I'll let you know :). Right now I'm browsing the source code to check if my memories were right.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML header should look like this (pay attention to proper header declarations):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<!-- ... -->
```

As described in [C.2.2 The util schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util).

Comment: The xml does contain the declarations you mentioned.

Comment: @aces. is `xsi:schemaLocation` there as well?

Comment: yes there is...I decided against adding rest of file for brevity. Can you please take a look at costi's comments, I have been trying all sorts of permutation and combinations to fix errors coming my way.